# Comparing list with string and printing matching line of list in string

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to compare a list against a text of strings and print the line that matches the element in the list

I have tried the below code, but getting lines which IP address is not in the list

```
acl = """
 access-list access_myside_in line 1 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.12 host 15.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 2 extended permit tcp host 18.1.2.2 host 15.1.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 3 extended permit tcp host 16.1.1.2 host 5.2.23.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 4 extended permit tcp host 18.2.1.2 host 15.2.1.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 5 extended permit tcp host 10.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.14 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 6 extended permit tcp host 13.1.1.2 host 10.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 7 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.2 host 12.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 8 extended permit tcp host 12.1.1.2 host 9.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 9 extended permit tcp host 15.1.1.2 host 15.22.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 10 extended permit tcp host 5.1.1.2 host 11.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 19 extended permit tcp host 1.1.1.2 host 15.2.13.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 25 extended permit tcp host 11.1.1.2 host 15.12.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 30 extended permit tcp host 8.1.1.2 host 5.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 31 extended permit tcp host 111.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.40 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 33 extended permit tcp host 18.1.11.2 host 17.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 40 extended permit tcp host 19.1.1.2 host 55.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 49 extended permit tcp host 20.1.1.2 host 80.2.3.4 eq ssh

"""

 myip = ['18.1.1.2', '20.1.1.2', '5.2.3.4', '15.2.3.4', '9.2.3.4', '8.1.1.2 ', '11.2.3.4']


acl_match = []
for a in myip:
   for b in acl.splitlines():
      if a in b:
         acl_match.append(b)


print(acl_match)
['access-list access_myside_in line 7 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.2 host 12.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 49 extended permit tcp host 20.1.1.2 host 80.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 1 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.12 host 15.2.3.4 eq ssh',
'access-list access_myside_in line 30 extended permit tcp host 8.1.1.2 host 5.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 31 extended permit tcp host 111.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.40 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 40 extended permit tcp host 19.1.1.2 host 55.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 1 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.12 host 15.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 31 extended permit tcp host 111.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.40 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 8 extended permit tcp host 12.1.1.2 host 9.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 7 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.2 host 12.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 30 extended permit tcp host 8.1.1.2 host 5.2.3.4 eq ssh', 
'access-list access_myside_in line 10 extended permit tcp host 5.1.1.2 host 11.2.3.4 eq ssh']
```

Comment: which lines do you mean? They seem all to be in the ip list. Please give an example of the expeced result vs the current result.

Comment: for example:  this line "access-list access_myside_in line 31 extended permit tcp host 111.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.40 eq ssh'," should not be in the result of the print statement as the IP address is not in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Format is consistant, you could search for each ip (with an whitespace before and after), in each line or you could use regex.

```
acl = r"""
access-list access_myside_in line 1 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.12 host 15.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 2 extended permit tcp host 18.1.2.2 host 15.1.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 3 extended permit tcp host 16.1.1.2 host 5.2.23.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 4 extended permit tcp host 18.2.1.2 host 15.2.1.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 5 extended permit tcp host 10.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.14 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 6 extended permit tcp host 13.1.1.2 host 10.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 7 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.2 host 12.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 8 extended permit tcp host 12.1.1.2 host 9.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 9 extended permit tcp host 15.1.1.2 host 15.22.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 10 extended permit tcp host 5.1.1.2 host 11.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 19 extended permit tcp host 1.1.1.2 host 15.2.13.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 25 extended permit tcp host 11.1.1.2 host 15.12.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 30 extended permit tcp host 8.1.1.2 host 5.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 31 extended permit tcp host 111.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.40 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 33 extended permit tcp host 18.1.11.2 host 17.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 40 extended permit tcp host 19.1.1.2 host 55.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 49 extended permit tcp host 20.1.1.2 host 80.2.3.4 eq ssh

"""

acl = [ x for x in  acl.splitlines()]

myip = ['18.1.1.2', '20.1.1.2', '5.2.3.4', '15.2.3.4', '9.2.3.4', '8.1.1.2 ', '11.2.3.4']

acl_match = []
for ip in myip:
    for string in acl:
        if string.find(" " + ip + " ")!=-1:
            acl_match.append(string)
            #print(string)

print(acl_match)

access-list access_myside_in line 7 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.2 host 12.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 49 extended permit tcp host 20.1.1.2 host 80.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 30 extended permit tcp host 8.1.1.2 host 5.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 1 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.12 host 15.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 8 extended permit tcp host 12.1.1.2 host 9.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 10 extended permit tcp host 5.1.1.2 host 11.2.3.4 eq ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to ensure that the ip addresses only match in a string if they are not preceeded or followed by any additional dots or digits.

```
import re

myip = ['18.1.1.2', '20.1.1.2', '5.2.3.4', '15.2.3.4', '9.2.3.4', '8.1.1.2', '11.2.3.4']
acl = """
access-list access_myside_in line 1 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.12 host 15.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 2 extended permit tcp host 18.1.2.2 host 15.1.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 3 extended permit tcp host 16.1.1.2 host 5.2.23.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 4 extended permit tcp host 18.2.1.2 host 15.2.1.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 5 extended permit tcp host 10.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.14 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 6 extended permit tcp host 13.1.1.2 host 10.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 7 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.2 host 12.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 8 extended permit tcp host 12.1.1.2 host 9.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 9 extended permit tcp host 15.1.1.2 host 15.22.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 10 extended permit tcp host 5.1.1.2 host 11.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 19 extended permit tcp host 1.1.1.2 host 15.2.13.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 25 extended permit tcp host 11.1.1.2 host 15.12.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 30 extended permit tcp host 8.1.1.2 host 5.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 31 extended permit tcp host 111.1.1.2 host 15.2.3.40 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 33 extended permit tcp host 18.1.11.2 host 17.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 40 extended permit tcp host 19.1.1.2 host 55.2.3.4 eq ssh
access-list access_myside_in line 49 extended permit tcp host 20.1.1.2 host 80.2.3.4 eq ssh
"""

# add negated class and escape dots, combine list into alternating regex pattern
pattern = re.compile('|'.join('[^\d.]{}[^\d.]'.format(ip.replace('.', '\.')) for ip in myip))
result = [s for s in acl.splitlines() if re.search(pattern, s)]
print(result)
# ['access-list access_myside_in line 1 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.12 host 15.2.3.4 eq ssh', 'access-list access_myside_in line 7 extended permit tcp host 18.1.1.2 host 12.2.3.4 eq ssh', 'access-list access_myside_in line 8 extended permit tcp host 12.1.1.2 host 9.2.3.4 eq ssh', 'access-list access_myside_in line 10 extended permit tcp host 5.1.1.2 host 11.2.3.4 eq ssh', 'access-list access_myside_in line 30 extended permit tcp host 8.1.1.2 host 5.2.3.4 eq ssh', 'access-list access_myside_in line 49 extended permit tcp host 20.1.1.2 host 80.2.3.4 eq ssh']
```